# ChatBot QnaMaker(Microsoft Azure) vs Lex (Amazon AWS)

Tags: azure, aws-lambda, amazon-lex, azure-qna-maker

Looking to make a chatbot on either Microsoft QnaMaker or Lex.

I would like to be able to make API calls to request answer to the question (node.js), train the bot using the API.
Currently I am using QnaMaker but unfortunately it doesn't seem to have response cards where user can click on it.

I know that Amaazon Lex allows this but do they allow training of bot through API?

Comment: QnA Maker do have response cards, called as Rich Cards, Read more about cards and attachments. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-rich-card-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make intents, put utterances and slots using the API's.
Lex support two types of API's - `Model Building API` and `Runtime API`. What you need is Model Building API.

As you are working with node.js, you should be referring [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html) and read more and more about [putIntent()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexModelBuildingService.html#putIntent-property) method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if I can have "Do you mean ... " instead of showing the default message that it doesn't know>?

Comment: what default message? amazon lex will show some message if it is unable to match any intent, are you talking about that?

Comment: Correct, right now I have it set to "I didn't understand you, what would you like to do?" 

For example, I train it to answer these two questions:
What is Apple iPad?
What is Apple iPhone?

If the user asks : What is Apple iMac?

Instead of showing "I didn't understand you, what would you like to do?", it should show the 2 closest match and ask user to select the correct question:
"Do you mean:
-What is Apple iPad?
-What is Apple iPhone?"

Comment: Apologies for the formatting.. I made a new thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51542131/chatbot-qnamaker-amazon-lex-do-you-mean